# When is "the" pronounced "dhee" / "dh" / "dhaa"?

Tags: definite-article, pronunciation

Is it "dhee", "dh" or "dhaa"? I have heard people pronounce it in these three ways. Are all of them correct or does it depend on context?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct pronunciation of "the"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123348/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the) And [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/117507/106592)

Comment: None od the linked questions dea with prononcing "the" starting with a D sound, so this is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the words that follow *the*: It's *dhee* before a vowel, and *dhaa* before a consonant.

That is how it is generally pronounced. When it is stressed for emphasis, the pronunciation becomes *dhee:* in every case.

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the emphasis usage – that's perhaps **the** main point. :^)

Answer (score 0):

When *the* is followed by a vowel sound, it is usually pronounced /ðiː/ (dhee), so that the *e* sounds like the *ee* in *see* or *fee*.

When *the* is followed by a consonant sound, it is usually pronounced /ðə/ (dhaa), so that the *e* sounds like the *a* in *comma* or the *u* in *sum*. However, the vowel is sometimes so short that it is barely noticeable (dh).

There are some exceptions though. When *the* is stressed for emphasis, it is usually pronounced /ðə/ (dhaa), regardless of the sound following it. However, in some dialects, it is usually pronounced /ðiː/ (dhee). It is also acceptable, though uncommon, to use any of these pronunciations when another would normally be used.

Comment: Except in the sentence above (and in my sentence here) where *the* is followed by *is* but is pronounced /ðə/.  ;-)

Comment: @Jim Hence the word _usually_.

Comment: This depends on the speaker's accent, or for learners, which accent they're hoping to mimic. In British and Australian English the *a* in *comma* and the *u* in *sum* are different vowels (`ə` and `ʌ` respectively).

Comment: In AmE, Australian English and many British dialects too, “the” is normally pronounced  ðə  unless speaking very slowly and formally or unless using particular emphasis.  Please listen closely to this video for example  (she says “the common way people speak” etc about 1 min. in): https://youtu.be/Zi2Z0Twx6cI